# Scala with JPA and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jpa-2.0

I want to write my dtos with scala, but it doesn't seem to work. When I want to depoly web app on the local webserver I get this message:

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidMetaDataException: 
Class de.cassys.gkasse.model.Application has application-identity 
and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. 
Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.
```

The confusing thing is, that I have defined a primary key field.. Look at this code:

```
@Table(name = "applications")
@Entity
class Application(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Key = null,
    var currentVersion: String = null,
    var certificate: Array[Byte] = null,
    var created: Date = null,
    var exec: Array[Byte] = null)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Using which version of GAE JPA plugin?

Comment: errm, no ... GAE JPA. It is a jar called "datanucleus-appengine".

Comment: so try v2.0.0. No idea if that will have an impact but v1.1.5 uses ancient software

Comment: Hmm. The question is whether google app engine accepts v2.0.0.0?

Comment: Accepts ? it provides it as an optional download IIRC, and after all its their plugin ;-)

Comment: Hmm. After the configuration I got this message: No persistence providers available for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.
What is to change?

Comment: Oh.. If I remove the data provider element in the persistence.xml file, the app deployes, but then I get the same message as before the update of datanucleus :-(

Comment: For moving to v2 look at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/UpgradingToVersionTwo